# how to generate entity classes from standalone tool

Tags: database, netbeans, entity

Is there any standalone tool may give result like netbeans `generate entity classes from database` or how can i use netbeans' `generate entity classes from database` feature from command line ?

 For example: `java -jar generate-entity url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1520:orcl user=x password=x path=entity/`